# How can I share data value over all application

Tags: angular

I have tried using local storage and cookies and it is working fine for me but the issue is any one can access that data easily.

Is there any way that we get data from our backed end and store that data in some globalvariable and can make use of that value in over al application?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? Behaviour subjects and observables in services may of use to you.

Comment: @David  Angular 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use service for that, create service add `providedIn: "root"`, so it will be available across all application and will be singleton instance also, you can put your data in there

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataService {
  public data: any;
}
```

and inject this service anywhere you want in the application

Comment: How can i store list of array in provideIn, Also can you give me small example that in which way I can fetch the data in other component? As I am new in angular

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static variable like this

```
export class Global{ 
    public static GlobalVar : any;
}
```

If you set `Global.GlobalVar = yourobject;`

you can access value from another component with

```
let globalobj = Global.GlobalVar;
```

But this way, `GlobalVar` will be reset if you refresh your page.

Comment: I think there should be some other way to full my approach

Answer (score 1):

If localstorage is not an option, but you want to persist the data even on page refresh, you can overcome this by doing the httprequest, store it in a global variable. Each component would subscribe to this function, and if the global variable has a value, return an observable of that or then make the http-request. The consumer doesn't care where the data comes from, just that it gets it. So create a service or use an existing one...

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class MyService {
   myData: any; // PLEASE do not use 'any', type your data instead!

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   myHttpRequest(): Observable<any> {
     if (myData) {
       return of(myData);
     } else  {
       return this.httpClient.get<any>('...').pipe(
         tap((data) => this.myData = data),
         catchError(() => /** do stuff **/)
       )
     }
   }
}
```

Then the component that wants the data, just subscribes to `myHttpRequest`:

```ts
// ...

constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.myHttpRequest()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data); // here's your data!
    });
}
```

And once again... don't use `any`, type your data!